# How can I stayed logged in as ADMINISTRATOR itself after logging out from a user?

Tags: administration, remote-access, grant-login-access

I was able to login as a different user from Admin User using the "login" link available in the user record of "Users" once I enabled the "Login Access Policies". But whenever I am logging off from the user I am completely logging out from Salesforce.

I knew that some setting is available in Salesforce to switch me back to Admin itself once I logged off from a User. But I am not getting that setting, Can you please help me to identify that setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Setup, enter Session Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Session Settings.

Make sure "Force relogin after Login-As-User" is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can not find "Force relogin after Login-As-User" in lightning. Change to classic and then go to se up and go to session setting, here you can find "Force relogin after Login-As-User" checkbox. Set it false.

[image]

Comment: Just a note here to avoid any confusion: this is supported on Lightning by now.